# how to scramble and then unscramble a list of elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, cryptography

```
list = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}; 
scrambledList=scramble[list]
```

> {"b", "d", "a", "c"}

```
unscramble[scrambledList]
```

> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}

what is a cool way to do this in Mathematica for a list of length $n$?

Comment: RandomSample + Sort?

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
scramble[li_] := 
 Permute[li, per = RandomPermutation[Length[list]]; 
  rep = InversePermutation[per]; per]; 
unscramble[li_] := Permute[li, rep];
```

produces:

```
scrambledList = scramble[list]
{"c", "a", "e", "b", "d"}

unscramble[scrambledList]
{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
```